# Postgresql pass multiple ranges and check if value in range

Tags: postgresql

I have a user table that has age column. I need to be able to dynamically create set of ranges and pass it to the procedure, for example:

```
[
  [0, 10],
  [10, 18],
  [18, 35],
]
```

As a result, it needs to return values count that belong to each range. Example:

```
|min|max|count|
---------------
|  0| 10|   24|
| 10| 18|  111|
| 18| 35|    0|
```

How can I implement such procedure?

Comment: *and check if the value within this range* - which "value" should be checked? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of [ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and use that to join to the table then group by the matched range:

```
with ranges (range) as (
  values 
    ( int4range(10,30) ), 
    ( int4range(10,18) ), 
    ( int4range(18,35) )
)
select r.range, count(t.age)
from ranges r
  left join the_table t on t.age <@ r.range
group by r.range;
```